# floated divs to vertically line up

Tags: css

I would like the following floated divs to line up vertically: The 4th div of class "box1"
 should start at the bottom (after 5px margin) of the div that is above it, not at the bottom of the lowest div in the entire upper row, same for the following divs.
how can i do that with css. 
(floating is not a must if there is another way to achieve this with css only)

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/paulmovie/vusd7hqx/2/)

html:

```
<div id="conainer">
    <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing eli
    </div>
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna al
    </div>
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
    </div>
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin
    </div>
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  </div>
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ul
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#conainer {display:block;}
.box1 {width: 31%; display:inline-block; border: thin solid black; margin:5px; float:left;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately CSS won't help you here. Look into [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS by itself may be extremely hard to set up rules like that to work with. However, if you know which boxes are going to be aligned on top of which boxes, then you could set up columns like so:

```
<div id="conainer">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing eli
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicin
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna al
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris 
        </div>
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.  </div>
        </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="box1">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ul
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, apply the CSS to each column to float left, while the boxes inside of it float to the bottom.

```
#conainer {
    display:block;
}
.column {
    width: 31%;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}
.box1 {
    border: thin solid black; 
    margin:5px; 
    float: bottom;
}
```

[Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusd7hqx/4/)

Also, depending on what you're trying to achieve, equal height divs may help solve your problem. [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dv0py0fm/)

Comment: If there is a third line, this answer maybe not fit for the question.

Comment: Depending on what the asker wants, it may. If there is a third or fourth line, all he has to do is add the boxes he wants into their respective column. However, for an extremely fluid solution with dynamically sized boxes, I don't think CSS is strong enough by itself...

Comment: Guess this is the very basics of grid design/positioning... with no js